# WPF Dependency Injection Using .Net Framework and ServiceProvider

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, .net-4.8

I have some WPF code that is written in the .Net Framework. 4.8.  (I can't move to .Net because of dependency issues.)

But I would like to make use of Dependency Injection.  I call `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` and then add all my views and view models to the dependency injection system.

The problem I have is that when I want to embed a view in another one, it does not create it from dependency injection.  Instead it just "news" it up.

So for example, one of my views has this in it:

```
<ContentControl>
    <rasViews:RasView/>
</ContentControl>
```

When this is hit, it does not use dependency injection to put that view in, it just creates a new `RasView`.

I totally get why it does not use DI here.  But I need a way to tell it to go ask the DI system for that view (instead of just making a new one).

**Is there some way I can get WPF to ask the DI system for a view in XAML?**  (Again, I am using .Net Framework, not .Net)

Comment: How do you think your dependency injection would work at design time?

Comment: @TomTom -  While nice to have, design time is not critical for me.

Comment: Well, then maybe you write your own IDE and standard, because this is IIRC (not done .NET 4.x for ages) the reason that DI was not considered there. That said,there are frameworks that do it, but from the other side - you assume a non visual tree and then put via some sort injection the visual parts around it.

Comment: @TomTom - I hardly think making my own IDE and standard is needed.  If worse came to worse, I can break out Prism (it does this, but adds more complexity that I want).  I was just hoping people had an easy way to get XAML to look at the DI container when it makes a view (instead of calling `new`).

Comment: f you want to go that way - Caliburn Micro.

Comment: A ContentControl would dynamically load a view by means of [data templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). There would be a DataTemplate with DataType set to the type of a view model in a ResourceDictionary. The DataTemplate would contain a specific view that should be loaded for this specific view model. When you assign an instance of the view model to the Content of a ContentControl (usually by data binding), the DataTemplate would automatically be applied.

Comment: The solution suggested by Clemens is the way you properly use Dependency Injection with WPF. And why do you think you need to inject any dependencies into the view? A control should always be independent. that's why XAML requires a control to have a default constructor which is the only constructor called by the engine). UI is generally not a candidate for Dependency Injection. You gain nothing except from adding complexity.

Comment: So, if your problem is about picking the right view dynamically (without the XAML declaration) then use DataTemplates. If you want to inject dependencies into the control, then simply don't do it. Follwing Clemens advice will give you the opportunity to extend your application by injecting new view models into your host view model and by adding new associated implicit DataTemplates for each new view model. WPF will do the mapping for you (e.g. when binding the view model to the ContentControl it will load the DataTemplate to show the content for example a RasView).